# How to follow DRY in that javascript-array-of-objects-case?

Tags: javascript, angular, functional-programming

I'm getting some complex array of objects from api via classic angular service. I need to change some objects, that do not contains some specific fields. For example...

```
this.myService.getStuff(stuff => {
  const finalStuff = stuff.map(one => one.a ? one : {...one, ...{a: 'any a'}});
})
```

Well, it works great. But what if I need to check the existence of *a* and *b*? It's gonna be...

```
this.myService.getStuff(stuff => {
  const finalStuff = stuff.map(one => one.a ? one : {...one, ...{a: 'any a'}})
                          .map(one => one.b ? one : {...one, ...{b: 'any b'}});
})
```

Well, it still works great, but it doesn't look great at all.
So my question is - how to achieve the same thing but without two almost identical *maps*?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just wondering, do you ever want to set multiple properties when `a` is not present? Why use the spread operator? I.e. why `{...one, ...{a: 'any a'}}` and not `{...one, a: 'any a'}`?

Comment: what about the build in filter method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to spread the default `a` and `b`s *initially*, and spread the whole `one` after, that way if any `a` or `b` already exists on the object, it will overwrite the default values provided:

```js
const stuff = [
  { a: 'a', b: 'b', foo: 'foo'},
  { b: 'b', foo: 'foo'},
  { a: 'a', foo: 'foo'},
  { foo: 'foo'},
]
console.log(stuff.map(one => ({
  a: 'any a',
  b: 'any b',
  ...one
})));
```

Or, for less spreading, use `Object.assign` instead:

```js
const stuff = [
  { a: 'a', b: 'b', foo: 'foo'},
  { b: 'b', foo: 'foo'},
  { a: 'a', foo: 'foo'},
  { foo: 'foo'},
]
console.log(stuff.map(one => Object.assign(
  {
    a: 'any a',
    b: 'any b'
  },
  one
)));
```

Comment: First example could be simplified: `stuff.map(one => ({a: 'any a', b: 'any b', ...one}))`

Answer (score 2):

Write a factory function, and generate the almost identical maps programmatically.

```
function addDefaultFactory(propertyName) {
    return (one) => 
        one[propertyName] ?
            one :
            {...one, ...{[propertyName]: `any ${propertyName}`}
}

this.myService.getStuff(stuff => {
  const finalStuff = stuff
        .map(addDefaultFactory("a"))
        .map(addDefaultFactory("b"));
```

Answer (score 2):

There's even yet another alternate approach using object spread operator and defaults:

```
this.myService.getStuff (stuff => {
  const finalStuff = stuff.map (
     ({ a = 'x' , b = 'y', ...rest }) => ({ ...rest, a, b })
  ) 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could always do it in a less FP manner:

```
this.myService.getStuff(stuff => {
  const finalStuff = stuff.map(one => {
    if (!one.a) one.a = 'any a';
    if (!one.b) one.b = 'any b';
    return one;
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but I prefer more functional style.